# ActiveMQ 5.7.0 - Duplicate dispatch on connection

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel, messagebroker

I frequently get log messages like that (bellow) on my consumer.

How to avoid that?

> 16/09/2013 14:02:36  WARN (ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1348) -
>   Duplicate dispatch on connection:
>   ID:tablets-prod-43952-1379342529758-1:4 to consumer:
>   ID:tablets-prod-43952-1379342529758-1:4:20:1, ignoring (auto acking)
>   duplicate...

Notes

> - Both, consumer and producer connect to the broker using the [failover
>     transport](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html)
> - I have only a single instance of ActiveMQ

Connection string for producer and consumer

> failover:(ssl://" + ip + ":" + port +
>   ")?maxReconnectAttempts=-1&timeout=5000

Broker config

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false">
          <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
          </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
        <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false">
          <pendingQueuePolicy>
            <vmQueueCursor/>
          </pendingQueuePolicy>
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Another problem is:

My consumer frequently receive duplicated messages. I mean two messages with the same body/payload. I know that because i have my own id inside the body that i send only once.

Any master can help me?

Comment: can you share the properties for the broker (either set by code or config)

Comment: @alihaider Thank you for reading. The post has been updated.

Comment: I believe the log stmt is generated as a warning message if this is missed:  if (this.info.isBrowser() || !session.connection.isDuplicate(this, md.getMessage()))

Comment: on the consumer end, I am guessing you're going with auto_ack.  Is optimizeAcknowledge set to true (for batch acks - could be causing an issue)